# Create userInfo container in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm working with setting a new exportable class that can export constants with value in react.

I initiate `states` in my export class, how do I export the variables and retrieve the values.

I want to make the `states` into constant, and export the constant so I can retrieve it by importing the class in another JS file.

How do I do it, and how do I get the value of the constant.

Underneath is the concept what I got from

`UserInfo.js`

```
  `export default class UserInfo extends React.Component {
   state = {
     userName: null,
     userType: null,
     userEmail: null,
     userCourse: [],
     registeredCourse: []
   }
    this.setState({
     userName: 'a',
     userType: 'b',
     userEmail: 'c',
     userCourse: ['d','e','f'],
     registeredCourse: ['g','h']
    })
    render(){
       const userType = this.state.userType
       return(
         userType
     )
    }`
```

`user.js`

```
`import UserInfo from './UserInfo'

 class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <div>{UserInfo.userName}</div>
      )
    }
 }`
```

Comment: It's hard to say what you're trying to achieve here. Can you give a little bit more context about what this class is going to be used for? You say "export the variables and retrieve the values," but from where?

It's not quite clear to me what the purpose of the constant is, either. An example use case might be helpful.

Comment: @StevenKang, I edit my question hope it give you a better sense of what you asking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways :

1. Declare state outside the App class and then you can export it.

   ```
   export const states= {
     userName: 'a',
     userType: 'b',
     userEmail: 'c',
     userCourse: ['a','b','c'],
     registeredCourse: ['a','b']
   };


   export default class UserInfo extends React.Component {
    enter code here
   }

   render(){
      console.log(`state is: ${ state}`);
   }
   ```

   Import it in another class like this

   ```
   import { UserInfo, states, } from 'path/to/UserInfo';

   console.log(`test is: ${ test }`);
   ```
2. Or you can use Static property to access it in another module.

   ```
   class State extends React.Component {
         static states= {
            userName: 'a',
            userType: 'b',
            userEmail: 'c',
            userCourse: ['a','b','c'],
            registeredCourse: ['a','b']
         };
   }
   ```

   And then use it

   ```
   console.log(State.states);
   ```

Comment: for the first solution If I have to set the `states` in the class. does it change the value? or the second one fits me more

Comment: sorry, I didn't make my question clear, is it the same concept?

Comment: Paritosh's answer is along the lines you should be looking for. If you simply want to have data in a variable called `states` that is a constant, it doesn't need to be a component. If you try to change the value of `states`, it will not change or will give you an error.

Comment: @StevenKang, I want to turn my states into constant then export tho